# Navbar tintColor not respected on iOS 7 compatibility mode for iOS 6 app?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, ios7

My app's navbar which is blue has suddenly changed to black/gray on iOS 7. My app was not upgraded to iOS 7 yet nor recompiled using Xcode 5. I was expecting to look exactly the same on iOS 7 with is compatibility mode for older compiled iOS 6, but I guess I was wrong?

Is this a bug or that's the intended behaviour?

For your information I'm not using a `UINavigationController`. Just a simple `UIView` in a nib with a navbar directly dragged from the Interface Builder.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is this:

```
UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor redColor];  
if ([navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)])
{
    navigationBar.barTintColor = tintColor;
}
else
{
    navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor;
    navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

In iOS7 the property tintColor from UINavigationBar changed to just tint the buttons (leftBarButtonItem/rightBarButtonItem) to declare the user they are tappable. The new way to "tint" the whole bar is by using barTintColor (available since iOS7).

There is one more difference:

Prior iOS7 the translucent property of UINavigationBar was `NO` by default, now it is `YES`.

Hope this helps you. :)

Best,
Sascha

Comment: I understand it's not supported for newer apps compiled under Xcode 5 using the iOS 7.0 SDK and I need to check that with a condition, but mine is still compiled under iOS 6.1 SDK. I haven't touched it in months.

Comment: Aaaah allaire, I think I know your issue, I also ran into this some month ago. You have the iOS6 style, but the bar has the wrong color. I had this issue also during WWDC. I think they changed it with iOS7 beta 4. May you check, if you have installed the newest iOS7 on your test device?

Comment: Exactly, the bar color is dark gray, but the buttons remained dark blue.

Answer (score -1):

On iOS 7 the default color for the navbar is white. Blue is the default navcolor in iOS 6, so maybe it's just setting it to the default for that OS version. That is assuming your navbar is that default iOS 6 blue.

Comment: No it's not the default blue, I used the tintColor property.